# How can automatic ticks be made "outie"?

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

By default, `FrameTicks` stick into the data area in a way that is sometimes uncomfortable.

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I see that I can create "outie" ticks manually using

```
Plot[
 Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0, {0, 0.01}}, {Pi, Pi, {0, .01}}, {2 Pi, 2 Pi, {0, 0.01}}, {3 Pi, 3 Pi, {0, 0.01}}}, {{-1/2, -1/2, {0, 0.01}}, {1/2, 1/2, {0, 0.01}}}, None, None}
]
```

[image]

But I want to use the automatic tick positions, sizes and labels. I can (kind of) achieve this so:

```
With[
 {originalPlot = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]},
 Show[originalPlot, 
  FrameTicks -> AbsoluteOptions[originalPlot, FrameTicks][[1, 2]] /. {a_, b_, {c_, d_}, e___} :> {a, b, {d, c}, e}]
 ]
```

[image]

There are (at least) three problems with this approach:

1. Extra vertical-axis tick labels have been inserted; all vertical-axis ticks appear to have been converted to minor ticks.
2. Trailing decimal points have been added to the integer tick labels.
3. `FrameStyle` no longer affects the ticks, apparently because the `ReplaceAll` solution hardcodes the `FrameTicks` style before `FrameStyle` is applied:

An example of correct application of `FrameStyle` (with default, "innie" ticks):

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

An example of broken application of `FrameStyle`:

```
With[
 {originalPlot = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray]},
 Show[originalPlot, 
  FrameTicks -> AbsoluteOptions[originalPlot, FrameTicks][[1, 2]] /. {a_, b_, {c_, d_}, e___} :> {a, b, {d, c}, e}]
]
```

[image]

How can this approach be improved to address these problems?

Comment: Unfortunately once you start customizing ticks, you lose most things that automatic ticks provide.  What I usually do is use the CustomTicks package (part of [LevelScheme](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/)) which is very customizable and closely mimics the automatic tick generation.

Comment: @Szabolcs I too use LevelScheme sometimes, but it'd be nice to have a native way of doing this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As I already experienced in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14937/automatizing-psfrag-export)  and @halirutan pointed out to me in chat, there seems to be a bug in `AbsoluteOptions` that causes the additional ticks. I doubt that there is an easy way to fix this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just use PlotRangePadding? E.g. `Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {.3, .1}]`

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2969/121

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a (somewhat buggy) function to do exactly this a while back. It basically takes a plot, finds the ticks, makes them negative length and replots the plot.

```
outsideTickPlot[plot_] := Module[{ticks, function, newticks},
  ticks = Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions@plot;
  function = {#1, SetPrecision[#2, Infinity], {-1, 1}*#3, #4} &;
  newticks = Apply[function, ticks, {2}];
  Show[plot, Ticks -> newticks]
  ]
```

and here is an example:

```
outsideTickPlot[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

The documentation for `FrameTicks` shows ways to define functions that get passed the minimum and maximum of your data, and then produce the kinds of ticks you require. To get "nice" divisions, use the `FindDivisions` function. To get "outie" ticks, you need a (small) positive argument in the second element of the pair-list at the end of the list specifying the tick - the 0.005 here.

```
myticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[{i, i, {0, 0.005}}, {i, FindDivisions[{min, max}, 10]}]
```

You can then specify:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x , 0 , 4 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {myticks[##] &, None}}]
```

[image]

You can be even fancier with a tick function definition like this:

```
myticks[min_, max_, n_] := 
 Table[{i, 
   Switch[Head[i], Integer, i, Rational, N@i, True, i], {0, 
    0.005}}, {i, FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]}]
```

This makes sure you don't get fractions as your tick label, while leaving integers alone.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x , 0 , 4 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{myticks[##, 5] &, myticks[##, 5] &}, {myticks[##] &, None}}]
```

[image]

One thing to watch out for is that "outie" ticks shrink the framed area, the larger you make them, for a given `ImageSize`. This might matter to you if you are composing your plots in a `Grid` or something.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[tickF]
tickF[t1_: {0., .02}, t2_: {0., .01}] := Replace[Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][##], 
  {{t_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ} :> {t, l, t1}, {t_, "", _, c___} :> {t, "", t2, c}}, 1] &;
```

Examples:

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,  FrameTicks -> (tickF[] {{1, 1}, {1, 1}})]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{tickF[], tickF[{.02, .02}, {.01, .01}]}, 
    {tickF[{.02, .02}, {0, .01}],  tickF[{.02, 0}, {.01, 0}]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
s[j_] := Table[{j i, j i, {0, 0.02}}, {i, -100, 100}];p[j_] := Table[{ j i/5, "", {0, 0.01}}, {i, -99, 99}];ticks[j_] := ArrayFlatten[{{s[j]}, {p[j]}}];


Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10},LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Times", Black},Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {{ticks[0.5], 
None}, {ticks[2], None}}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

Note that j reprsents the size step on the axes or you can say the size of the main tick.
[image]